# Listing files from multiple paths

Tags: javascript, fso

I'm writing a small app that needs to list files from multiple paths.

Iv tried to do somthing like this but its only shows me the first path.

Any clue why is that?

Here is the code:

```
var wsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var FSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

function window.onload() {
    var s = "";
    var paths = FSO.OpenTextFile("bin\\paths.txt")

    while (!paths.AtEndOfStream) {
    content = paths.ReadLine();
    s += content;
    loadMediaFolders(s);
    }
    stat.innerHTML= s;
}

function loadMediaFolders(wathPath) {
var str = "";
    var folder = FSO.GetFolder(wathPath);
        var mainFolders = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);
            for (; !mainFolders.atEnd(); mainFolders.moveNext()) {

                var FolderPath = mainFolders.item().Path;

                var files = FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath);
                var sbFiles = new Enumerator(files.Files);

                for (; !sbFiles.atEnd(); sbFiles.moveNext()) {
                var FilleName = sbFiles.item().Name;

                str += FilleName;
                }
            }
    stat.innerHTML= str;
}
```

This is how the paths are stored inside the file:

```
F:\\stuff\\Media\\Movies\\
D:\\Media\\Movies\\
```

Comment: No need to use double slashes for the path separator in the text file - that kind of escaping is only for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop reading the folder paths, you are concatenating the paths before passing them to `loadMediaFolders(...)`. The first one will work since `s` will be `F:\stuff\Media\Movies\`, the second time `s` will be `F:\stuff\Media\Movies\D:\Media\Movies\`.

Try something like this

```
while (!paths.AtEndOfStream) {
    content = paths.ReadLine();
    loadMediaFolders(content);
}
```

`loadMediaFolders(...)` already writes the result to `stat.innerHtml`, so that line can be removed too. Keep in mind that you might be overwriting all of `stat.innerHtml`, when you really wanted to concatenate the results, in `loadMediaFolders(...)`.

Comment: Yes - `stat.innerHTML= str;` is overwriting the results; try `stat.innerHTML+= str;`.

Comment: that worked like a charm :) is there a way to output the result in one table row? Iv tried to do that but it brakes down to tow table rows :(

Comment: outside the for loop:
var Stable = "<table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2 border=0><tr>";
inside the loop:
str += "<td>"+FilleName+"</td>";
outside the for loop:
var Etable = "</tr></table>"; stat.innerHTML += Stable+str+Etable;

Comment: still not working :( gives me those tow blady rows :( any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @ABA3DD: if I understand what you're trying to do, it requires a bit of refactoring. You might need to save all file/folder names in arrays and then write the output after all data has been collected. That sounds like a separate stack overflow question based on the new code though, a bit too complicated for comments only. I believe this question has been answered, and if you agree, it would be good if you accepted this answer as the correct one =)

Comment: I agree and accept the answer :). I'll statr a new question :) thanks for the help u rocks!!!!!